# How to access environment variable in post-build access for jira plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jql, post-build

I installed `JIRA Plugin` for the jenkins. It add some action in `Post-build Action` menu. One of the action is **JIRA: Update relevant issues**.

When I try to access Environment Variable, it gives error.

```
WARNING: jira rest client get issue from jql search error. cause: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key '$MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key '$MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:289)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:262)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:91)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:69)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.get(DelegatingPromise.java:107)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraRestService.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(JiraRestService.java:177)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSession.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(JiraSession.java:136)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.selector.JqlIssueSelector.findIssueIds(JqlIssueSelector.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.Updater.perform(Updater.java:85)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater.perform(JiraIssueUpdater.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key '$MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:176)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:170)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:11)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

`$MY_ISSUE_ID` is valid environment variable, and I am able to access it on other section of the build.

I tried `issue=${XXXX}`, `issue=XXXX`, `issue="$XXXX"` etc... but all gives error.

What is the way to pass `environment variable` in **jql** for `post build action`.

When I gave `issue=MYPROJECT-1234`, it works fine. But, I want to set `MYPROJECT-1234` as environment variable.